# Wordpress Div Tags in Posts

Tags: wordpress, html, tinymce, blogs, posts

The TinyMCE editor in WordPress 3 is removing my div tags if I switch from HTML view to visual and update my page. What would be the best way to prevent this from happening?

I have a styled horizontal rule that I enter into the pages/posts by putting the following code:

```
<div class="hr"></div>
```

Comment: check your valid_elements setting!!

Answer (score 1):

You could also create a shortcode by entering the following in your themes functions.php file:

```
function hr_shortcode( $atts, $content = null ) {
  return '<div class="hr"></div>';
}
add_shortcode( 'hr', 'hr_shortcode' );
```

Then you would just need to add [hr] into your post.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried converting them to entities?

```
&gt;div class="hr"&lt;&gt;/div&lt;
```

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress strips certain tags out automatically. Try this plugin that allows you to specify which tags you don't want stripped.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tinymce-valid-elements/

You can also manually hack the tiny MCE config files, but I think sticking with the plugin is the easiest and safest bet.